# select2 and jQuery.noConflict()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

in my project I have 2 version of jQuery: 1.6.2 (used on all project) and 1.12.4 used for more recent javascript.

Now we need to use select2 jquery plugin and we have this code:

```
jq112 = jQuery.noConflict( true );
var dataSelect = [];

jq112(document).ready(function () {
    if (dataSelect.length > 0) {
        var select = jq112('<select>').select2({
            data: dataSelect
        });

        jq112('#box').prepend(select);
    }
});
```

But if I load page I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jq112(...).select2 is not a function
```

How can use select2 with jquery.noConflict() ?

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

> How can use select2 with jquery.noConflict() ?

Load `select2` after loading that version of jQuery, before loading any other:

```
<script src="jquery-v1.12.js"></script>
<script>
var jq112 = jQuery.noConflict(); // <== Do not pass true
</script>
<script src="select2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-whatever-other-version.js"></script>
```

The reason for not passing `true` in the `noConflict` is that that will release the `jQuery` symbol as well as `$`, but plugins need **some** way to plug into jQuery (and any decent plugin uses `jQuery`, not `$`, to do that).

> in my project I have 2 version of jQuery: 1.6.2 (used on all project) and 1.12.4 used for more recent javascript

Strongly recommend biting the bullet to upgrade the remainder of the project to something much more up-to-date.